# What will be the dimension of the $U$ subspace in $\mathbb{R}^4$ vectorspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

$U=\{ (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4):x_{1}-2x_2=0,x_1+x_2-x_3=0\}$ Well I can write that

$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
        1 & -2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0
        \end{array}\right]
$$

after that

$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
        1 & 0 & -2/3 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & -1/3 & 0 & 0
        \end{array}\right]
$$

so $x_1= \frac 2 3 x_3$ and $x_2= \frac 1 3 x_3$ and $x_3,x_4$ are free variables so will be the dimension $2$?

Comment: This means that the dimension is equal to $2$. You have $2$ free variables and once you fix them, the other two variables are also set, so your dimension is $2$ and not $4$.

Comment: I sorry, I wanted to write 2.

Comment: But I'm not sure that my explanation is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your working, if $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) \in U$, then
$$(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = \left(\frac{2}{3}x_3, \frac{1}{3}x_3, x_3, x_4\right) = x_3\left(\frac{2}{3}, \frac{1}{3}, 1, 0\right) + x_4(0, 0, 0, 1).$$
Therefore, you have proven that $U \subseteq \operatorname{span}\lbrace (2/3, 1/3, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1) \rbrace$. This is a span of two linearly independent vectors (which thus form a basis for their span), and hence is dimension $2$. Therefore $U$ is at most dimension $2$. Show the other inclusion, and you're done.